# Which pattern to use for creating objects of multiple versions with different parameters?

Tags: java, design-patterns

My application makes a rest to call to a few other services via PUT by passing a "Service Request" object to that service. However, integration with a few new services required for us to maintain 3 different versions of the Service Request. I looked at the documentation for Builder Pattern in wikipedia and few other sites but could not find any thing confirming that I can use builder pattern for my usecase.

The three versions of service request objects we require are:

```
Version 1:

{
  id: "SomeGlConsumer",
  parameters: {
    m_id: 44551,
    m1_id: 695831032,
    r1: "EU",
    r2: "xyz",
    o1: 30,
    l1: 130,
    g1: "alksja",
    g2: 75,
    g3: "akjsa",
    g4: 2040,
    p1: "aks;alksa" 
    c1: "http:/xyz.com/services/gl"
  }
}

version 2:

{
  id: "SomeGlConsumer",
  parameters: {
    m1: 44551,
    m2: 695831032,
    r1: "EU",
    r2: "xyz",
    o1: 30,
    l1: 130,
    g: [
      {
        g1: "lksaskasa",
        g2: 228,
        g3: "alksjajslkajs",
        g4: 8400,
        p1: "kjsasjajsjak" 
     },
     {
       g1: "aslalsalksa",
       g2: 396,
       g3: "ajksaj",
       g4: 6350,
       p1: "akjsasa" 
     },
     {
       g1: "ajsajsa",
       g2: 397,
       g3: "aslalksa",
       g4: 6350,
       p1: "lkasal" 
     }
   ],
   c1: "http://abc.com/services/gl"
 }
}


version 3:

{
  c1: "Contribution Profit",
  c2: "http://abc.com/services/notifySetupStatus",
  a1:834,
  c3: {
    l1: 03/30/2013
  },
  m: {
    m1: 44551,
    m2: 695831032,
    r1: "EU",
    r2: "haasla",
    s1: "ES",
    o1: 30,
    l2: 130
  },
  g: [
    {
      g1: "aasassla",
      g2: 228,
      g3: "lkaskaskja",
      g4: 8400,
      p1: "ls;aksas",
      p2: "alsalska"  (Optional)
    },
    {
      g1: "aasassla",
      g2: 228,
      g3: "lkaskaskja",
      g4: 8400,
      p1: "ls;aksas",
    },
    {
      g1: "aasassla",
      g2: 228,
      g3: "lkaskaskja",
      g4: 8400,
      p1: "ls;aksas",
    }
  ],
  xyzservice_config: [ # service specific bucket
    {
      g1: "alksaks",
      c1: "kaskas" 
    },
    {
      g1: "akslaksa", 
    },
    {
      g1: "aslaksa",
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: why not Builder? I think it would work fine

Comment: By using builder, I can just build each version of this request individually but they do not have much properties in common to have a common abstract builder defined. please correct me if i am wromg

Comment: You're right, but this is the advantage of Builder, you don't need to define a number of constructors to satisfy different objects with different properties, the interface can be more or less the same and the constructor (Builder) is the same, and you can expand it as you wish. I used the Builder pattern for a very similar case. I will give you another option as answer because I have no more characters left :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm implemented already some API that are wrapped with a REST interface. The best solution for me was to use the command pattern. You can put all the arguments in a table and put it in the command object.

I would do a command object which contain a version property, an Id property and a HashMap or Hashtable to hold all different types of arguments that you may become. You could even susbstitute this hashMap with some kind of JSON object.

With this structure you're always flexible. It worked perfectly for me in systems with several methods and a big number of different data structures.